# wrap the text with a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following text inside a paragraph with a html new line at the end

```
<p class="pcontainer extend">
    First Text<br />
    Second Text<br />
    Third Text<br />
</p>
```

Now what I desirely want to do is to wrap those 3 text with a div so the output would be..

```
<p class="pcontainer extend">
    <div class="wrap">First Text</div><br />
    <div class="wrap">Second Text</div><br />
    <div class="wrap">Third Text</div><br />
</p>
```

as you can see each text has been wrapped with a div (), is there anyway I could achieve that through jquery or javascript approach?. So far im currently searching around for a solution but so far nothing is match to cater my needs. Any suggestions, recommendation and ideas, would love to hear! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is to filter non-empty text nodes and apply [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to them:

```
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
        && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<div class="wrap" />');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kEvm4/

Comment: working but why there are spaces like i set the margin to 0px and padding to 0px but still there are spaces between each others div? anyway, lets assume that the last content has no <br /> will it still work on that script too?